# Как правильно работать с однотипным потоком данных?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Для тренировки С++ пишу небольшой новостной агрегатор. Задался вопросом как идеологически правильно работать с данными.
К примеру, у меня есть новость, у нее есть несколько свойств (время, тема, содержание).
Как в таких случаях поступают?

1. Пишут общий класс с методами записи, показа и полями данных, каждое из которых соответствует свойству, и при необходимости получить нужную новость, просто пробегают по массивам полей, допустим по дате, и найдя нужное, по данному индексу вызывают другие поля, соответствующие этой новости?
2. Пишут общий класс с методами записи, показа. Так же создают класс новость для хранения данных. И при записи каждый раз создают отдельный объект-новость под каждую из них? Соответственно при приходе данных один общий объект начинает создавать объекты класса новость и пишет туда данные.

В книгах всегда пишут, что правильно сопоставлять программным объектам объекты из реального мира. Поэтому кажется неправильным забивать все данные в один класс. С другой стороны, есть ощущение, что так удобнее и быстрее будет работа с данными. Какой из методов будет быстрее в итоге и менее затратным в плане памяти? (Хотя мне кажется, что память будет занимать одинаково, ведь поля и там и там создаются, а больше накладных расходов и не будет)

Comment: Чтобы не развозить кисель, сделайте какой-нибудь вариант и если что-то будет в нем вызывать сомнения, спросите об этом конкретно.

Comment: Было интересно узнать методологию, про такое было просто негде спросить узнать. Примеров кода таких много, там ничего интересного, поэтому не стал прикладывать код, чтобы он не отвлекал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, то, что объекты отображают сущности реального мира — более-менее правильно. Я бы сказал просто, что они отображают сущности, конкретные или абстрактные.

Но вот что стоит разделить — это контент и представление.

Новость — это всего лишь новость, она как таковая *содержит* информацию (время, тема, содержание), возможно, содержит в том или ином виде ссылки на связанные новости, на свой источник и тому подобное. Эти структуры описывают контент.

Но новость не знает и не должна знать, в каком виде и где программа собирается её показывать. Хуже того, требования на показ могут меняться между различными приложениями, а также внутри самой программы. Например, для показа в браузере новость превращается в HTML, для показа в оконной программе — в набор контролов, для вывода в лог — одна строка (возможно, укороченная). Поэтому *показом* новости должен заниматься другой объект. Да, при этом класс, соответствующий новости, получится примитивным, но разве это плохо?

Что касается хранения данных, можно было бы в принципе написать и отдельный класс, сериализирующий новость (таким образом вы абстрагируетесь от того, сохраняете ли вы данные на диск или передаёте их по сети, например). Но часто в C++ сериализацию «упаковывают» в сам сериализируемый объект, т. к. в отсутствие рефлексии «посторонняя» реализация достаточно сложна.

Да, и новость является самостоятельной сущностью. Не пакуйте все новости в один класс, иначе вы не сможете иметь методы, обрабатывающие новость «по одной», у вас всей системе придётся знать, что новость адресуется индексом в какой-то таблице. И если в какой-то момент времени вы решите поменять структуру хранения новостей в памяти, вы не сможете это сделать, не переделывая всю программу.

---

Насчёт оптимизации по памяти, если у вас вместо одного объекта будет два, вы проиграете в сумме меньше 20 байт. Вы серьёзно думаете, что нелогичная структура программы ради такого ничтожного выигрыша по памяти стоит свеч?

Comment: А я б вообще не изобретал велосипед, и для **представления** новости использовал бы что-то общепринятое. В самом простом случае это RSS, в случае чуть посложней - Atom, и т.д. Пусть в виде своих каких-то объектов, не принципиально, главное чтобы оно легко превращалось в конечное представление.  Ну или что-то ещё, для чего вопросы записи/чтения/отображения уже давно решены.

Comment: У меня уже есть файл из 40000 новостей отобранных, я хочу их отсортировать потом, сделать фильтры. Мне показалась это удачные объекты для работы с данными, они понятные и имеют явные свойства. Поэтому этот код чисто для тренировки, так что RSS и Atom тут мне будут только мешать.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за как всегда отличный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Количество классов само по себе никак не влияет на производительность. В проектировании обычно считается, что классы должны отражать сущности *предметной области*, не обязательно реальные объекты. Например, в серии статей про [паладинов и оборотней](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) Эрик Липперт приходит к заключению, что при создании движка РПГ было бы ошибкой не представлять правила в виде данных.

Но, как я уже сказал в комментарии, don't dream it - do it. Cделайте хоть как-нибудь, а потом спрашивайте про места, которые показались вам неудачными.

Comment: Код я написал. В итоге выбрал просто сделать поле класса News внутри класса управляющего новостями. Вышло вроде удобно.

Answer (score 1):

Про объекты реального мира это большая сказка, которая была придумана во времена активной пиарной компании ООП. В учебниках всегда рассматривают слишком простые задачи в которых проектирование не потренируешь. Это мое субъективное мнение.

По сути вопроса. Сконцентрируйтесь на профите пользователя, думайте о том как он получит этот профит с помощью вашей программы и какой конкретно профит он хочет получить. Вот этот "результат" и следует проектировать.

Для средних и крупных проектов разрабытываются ТЗ, это наиболее достоверный источник информации о том чего хочет заказчик (но не всегда пользователь!). В этих ТЗ "результат" описан как сложный составной объект, так вот если слепо следовать букварям мы должны взять сущности из этого ТЗ и смоделировать поведение которое требуется этим же ТЗ. Так вот нихрена это не работает!

Часто сами разрабочики не понимают разницы между целями и задачами проекта. Цель - то что мы хотим получить, задачи - то как мы это достигаем. Учебники совершенно упускают этот ключевой момент.